# Gamertag and hasn't changed after paying for the service

Tags: xbox-one, xbox-network

A few weeks ago I paid 10 dollars to change my Xbox gamertag. It still hasn't changed. It says on the website that it's changed, but on the Xbox application & in Minecraft it displays my old one. I really don't want to experiment and pay another 10 dollars so how can I fix this?

Comment: What website are you checking to see if it's changed?

Comment: You should be talking to Microsoft support.

Answer (score 1):

In minecraft, it's supposed to be almost a month before it shows up in case you want to change it back. I don't know if this is the case, but when I changed mine, it said it'll take a few weeks and it did. I don't know much else. I hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest relogging into everything. For example for Minecraft sign out of Xbox Live and back into it and see if the name resyncs.

Answer (score 0):

You say that you don’t see a new tag? It’s actually there.It’s just that you aren’t able to SEE it.You say you don’t see it.But it’s on display to other players, actually.It’s just that you can’t see it.Also, make sure you don’t cash in another 10 dollars.
Hope this helps.